# Heroku thinks my ssh is in wrong place

Tags: git, heroku, ssh, chromium

Heroku is giving me permission denied when I try to ssh to it.

I was able to add my key successfully which is saved at `~/.ssh` in my user root.

However, when Heroku tries connecting I see it is for some reason looking inside of `/c/ChromeBrowser/depot_tools/.ssh/id_dsa` and not my actual user root folder.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku will try several keys (rsa, dsa, ...), all in `%HOME%` (or `$HOME`).
So you need to check that:

- Heroku is using the right account
- `HOME` is set to your local root `~/.ssh` folder meaning, set as a user environment variable `HOME` to `c:\Users\Robert`).

This has nothing to do with `ssh-agent`, which is only needed if your private key is passphrase-protected. I would recommend using a passphrase-less key for testing.
Here, Heroku does not find the right key anyway.

Comment: Yes, Heroku think your key is in the wrong place: what account is it using? What value is HOME set to?

Comment: @Robert What path should ~/.ssh be in your case?

Comment: c:\Users\Robert\.ssh\  but heroku thinks its in ChromeBrowser folder.

Comment: @Robert Then set HOME as a user variable (not system) to C:\Users\Robert, and open a new shell (to inherit that variable) and try again.

Comment: That worked! I added it as a user variable and pointed it to my users folder. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add the ssh key to your ssh-agent and it should work.

```
# add the default ~/.ssh keys to the ssh-agent
ssh-add

# restart the ssh-agent
eval $(ssh-agent)
```

---

#### `ssh-add`

> ssh-add adds RSA or DSA identities to the authentication agent, ssh-agent.
>   When run **without arguments**, it adds the files `~/.ssh/id_rsa`, `~/.ssh/id_dsa` and `~/.ssh/identity`.
>
> Alternative file names can be given on the command line

---

#### `eval $(ssh-agent)`

By calling eval you load the added ssh-key.

Comment: no it is only checking just the "/c/ChromeBrowser/depot_tools/.ssh/id_dsa" folder... i think this is due to a long while back i had a developer who setup the chroumim project on my windows computer and defaulted some variables. however i'm not sure how to switch it. so it doesn't just look there only.

Comment: go to the control panel, under system edit the path properties and edit your home folder